# How to change ccache type of MIT Kerberos

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, kerberos, single-sign-on, mitkerberos

The [MIT Kerberos Documentation](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/ccache_def.html) lists seven different ways to store Kerberos credentials:

1. API
2. DIR
3. FILE
4. KCM
5. KEYRING
6. MEMORY
7. MSLSA

At the moment my Kerberos setup is storing credentials in a file in the `/tmp`
directory. In my `krb5.conf` file the `ccache_type` option is set to 4 by default:

```
# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
        krb4_config = /etc/krb.conf
        krb4_realms = /etc/krb.realms
        kdc_timesync = 1
        ccache_type = 4
        forwardable = true
        proxiable = true
```

And in the MIT Kerberos Documentation about the [`krb5.conf`](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#libdefaults) file it says about the `ccache_type` option:

> This parameter determines the format of credential cache types created by kinit or other programs. **The default value is 4, which represents the most current format.** Smaller values can be used for compatibility with very old implementations of Kerberos which interact with credential caches on the same host.

It seems that the value of the `ccache_type` option does not correspond to the seven ccache types that the documentation lists. Since `4` specifies to use the "most current format" and not "KCM".

Therefore, my question is: **How can I configure Kerberos to use a different ccache type, for example a keyring or memory?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to alter the `KRB5CCACHE` environmental variable.
Usually you'll do this for all instances in `krb5.conf` as follows:

```
[libdefaults]
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

However, you can set it in other ways, e.g. `export KRB5CCNAME=KEYRING:persistent:$(id -u)`.